# How to fix DesiredCapabilities error in java appium?

Tags: java, appium

I am getting this error "The type org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files"

when I compile and run the program.

when I hover the mouse near the error location in the code this is the information its displaying.

""The type org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

```
package manoj_test;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;


import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElemen0t;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

public class tes12 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "0260dd0730971a0a");
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "/home/manoj/Downloads/xyz.apk");
AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),cap);



}

}
```

Comment: In my case I resolved it changing JVM, I had 11, and then changed it for 8.

Comment: I am learning Appium, and I am beginner. I got error while instantiate Desired Capabilities and the error as follows "**Cannot instantiate the type DesiredCapabilities**" I am using Eclipse for writing Java code, Maven version is 4.0.0, Selenium-Java version is 4.14.1, Java client version is 9.0.0, Maven complier version is 3.1, Appium version is 2.0.1, Java version is 1.8. If that above mentioned rectified, I can able to run the program I think so..

Answer (score 1):

Hope you are using Pom.xml to add dependencies.if that is the case check you have added bellow dependencies apart from appium dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.44.0</version>
</dependency>
```

if you still have same problem import bellow dependencies to your code.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;  
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
```

finally, you can add java client directly to your build path.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue while working With Appium. I observed that few build path libraries were fetched from other folders. So I just deleted those practice projects from which libraries were getting fetches so in my Project we was getting above error. Now after deleting all other practice projects and also clearing my project build path libraries . we again added external jars to java build path and now its working properly no issue thrown. added jars from "selenium-java-3.141.59" and "appium java client".
[image: Java Build path snapshot]